# Put a condition for a field within query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query :

```
$cond = "";
    if($cid >0 )
    {
        $quali = $this->getCandidatesQualification($cid);

        $cond = "WHERE emp_qualification LIKE '%$quali%'";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT
            emp_job_id,emp_job_profie,emp_qualification,emp_experience
        FROM
            tbl_emp_data
            $cond
        ORDER BY job_add_date DESC LIMIT 0,10   
    ";
    $res = $this->db->returnArrayOfObject($sql,$pgin = 'no', $odr='no');
```

Now what I want if `emp_qualification` field is equal to `any_graduate` I want to select all the jobs for the candidate even if his qualification is say `BA` .

Comment: What is `any_graduate`? Please give us more context if it is a field in another table.

Comment: `any_graduate` is if the field employer selects that it will be applicable to all graduates .

Answer (score 1):

so modify your WHERE clause to

```
WHERE emp_qualification LIKE '%$quali%' 
OR emp_qualification = 'any_graduate'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cond = '';
if($cid >0 ) {
    if ($this->getCandidatesQualification($cid) != 'any_graduate') {
        $cond = "WHERE emp_qualification LIKE '%{$this->getCandidatesQualification($cid)}%'";
    }
}
```

simplified, try this